# Java 8 stream error on JavaFX BarChart element

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, java-stream

I am receiving the following errors, when using streams on JavaFX `BarChart`'s `getData()`

```
error: invalid method reference
                .map(XYChart.Series::getName);
                            ^ non-static method getName() cannot be referenced from a static context

 error: incompatible types: invalid method reference
                .map(XYChart.Series::getName);
                     ^ method getName in class Series<X,Y> cannot be applied to given types
      required: no arguments
      found: Object
      reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length   where X,Y are type-variables:
    X extends Object declared in class Series
    Y extends Object declared in class Series
```

```
public class MainController{
        public BarChart barChart; // from fxml file
}
```

The following code will successfully print the class names of the BarChart;

```
List<XYChart.Series> test = barChart.getData();
List<String> testList = test.stream().map(XYChart.Series::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(testList);
```

however this piece of code will fail at compile time;

```
List<String> testList = barChart.getData().stream()
      .map(XYChart.Series::getName) // error line
      .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
System.out.println(testList);
```

Why is this error thrown and why it is only thrown in the first example but not in the latter one? What is making the difference between those two code examples?

*[run with Gradle and Java version 1.8.0_144]*

Comment: This happens because you did not specify what is the generic type of a `BarChart` (formal declaration for which is `BarChart<X extends Object, Y extends Object>`. The last example in particular would produce a compile *warning*, something along the lines of "unsafe cast" warning.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I updated my code.

Comment: The declaration `List<XYChart.Series> test` will produce a warning unless you explicitly suppress it in your IDE. Method references are resolved by the compiler in a manner that depends on the types of the references being used. Resolution of method references is [complex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) because there are many different possibilities as to how they can be resolved. If you use raw types you risk not providing enough information to the compiler to resolve the method reference.

Comment: I don't know exactly why the first version doesn't give an error, where the second one does, but I suspect explicitly typing the result of `barChart.getData()` as `List<XYChart.Series>` results in the compiler implicitly giving it the type `List<XYChart.Series<Object,Object>>`, which is enough for the method reference to resolve. In the second version, because `barChart` has raw type, there isn't enough information to resolve the method reference, because the result of `barChart.getData()` never has any valid type (raw or not).

Comment: The bottom line is that you simply should not be using raw types: there is absolutely no reason to do so unless you are interacting with legacy (pre-Java 5) code, which is not the case if you are using JavaFX 8 or later. (So, basically, you shouldn't care why the first gives no errors and the second gives an error: you simply shouldn't be writing this code in the first place.)

Comment: @James_D thank you very much, I understand now :)

Comment: @James_D small correction. The raw type `BarChart`’s `getData()` has a valid type, it’s the raw type `ObservableList` whose `stream()` method returns the raw type `Stream`. Of course, without knowing the element type, you can not use `.map(XYChart.Series::getName)` which requires the elements to be of type `XYChart.Series`. In the first version, the assignment to `List<XYChart.Series>` is already an *unchecked* conversion from the raw type `ObservableList` to `List<XYChart.Series>`. And the raw type `XYChart.Series` is *not* the same as `XYChart.Series<Object,Object>`.